# What code do i need to add to get this working against SharePoint online?

Tags: c#, sharepoint

Sorry for my bad english!

Some code in this section (see image) is missing. When i'm try to run it, i can't see exactly where i'm getting the exception!

My theory is that i'm missing context.Load or 
context.ExecuteQuery! But i'm not sure!

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzBon.png)

Comment: Please include your code in the question itself, not as an image.

Comment: Please don't post code as images, post it as text - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for how to format it. Also please include the exception itself (again, as text not an image).

Comment: You should put a breakpoint in your code and inspect it as it executes. You should also wrap you your code in a `try...catch` and inspect the error

Comment: What exception are you getting?